# Custom Login Path for ASP.NET CORE 6 and Azure AD

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-6.0

I currently have a page in "/login/index" with my logo and a form/button on it which on POST will initiate the challenge for MS Azure AD login to authenticate the user. The user is then redirected back to the home page after login. However, currently with the default setup for Azure AD authentication a user never sees this "/login/index" page because they are forced to MS Azures ADs login page for all request paths if not authenticated. Is there a way to force users to this initial login page I setup so that they can click the button to go authenticate?

My program.cs is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using Project.Models;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2016.Drawing.ChartDrawing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Login");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/files");
    });

//authentication pipline
var initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

//We are using this so we can find the modified date later on. If we move to Box or Onedrive we may not need this.
var RootPath = builder.Environment.ContentRootPath;
var WebPath = builder.Environment.WebRootPath;
var fileDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(RootPath).Parent.ToString(), "files");
IFileProvider physicalProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(fileDirectory);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(physicalProvider);

//Not needed. We are not using this level of abstraction but may move towards it one day so possibly keep.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBContext");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//We are making it so armsfiles are not accessible outside of arms so if we move to box or onedrive then the parameter may need to be removed.
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = physicalProvider,
    RequestPath = "/files"
});

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

app.Run();
```

Before using Azure AD for authentication I would use this cookie policy in my startup class (I have since converted to minimal hosting model in program.cs) to force users to the login page (which although different now but still similar concept to what I am trying to achieve):

```
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(cookieOptions =>
        {
            cookieOptions.Cookie.Name = "UserLoginCookie";
            cookieOptions.LoginPath = "/Login/";
            cookieOptions.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            cookieOptions.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the official doc about [`Quickstart: Add sign-in with Microsoft to a web app`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core). And I [downloaded the repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/archive/aspnetcore3-1-callsgraph.zip) and test it.

You can check the test result first, please confirm if this is what you want?

#### Test Result

[image]

**What I changed in the sample project**

1. Change the appsettings.json file in project.
2. Copy the code from `Home/Index` method, and create a new page `LoginSuccess` then paste the code to `Home/LoginSuccess`. And modify the attribute, you can copy my sample code directly.

   ```
   using System.Diagnostics;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
   using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
   using Microsoft.Graph;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
   using active_directory_aspnetcore_webapp_openidconnect_v2.Models;

   namespace active_directory_aspnetcore_webapp_openidconnect_v2.Controllers
   {
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,
                          GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
             _logger = logger;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
       }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            //var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            ViewData["ApiResult"] = "Demo";//user.DisplayName;

            return View();
        }

        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginSuccess()
        {
            var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            ViewData["ApiResult"] = user.DisplayName;

            return View();
        }


        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
   }
   ```
3. Create LoginSuccess page(copy from index page).

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: So in this example the signin and signout is in the navigatino in _layout which is shared among views. I was hoping to have all pages for an unauthenticated user to be redirected to /login/index (a seperate page). Your code is helpful though but not exactly what I was thinking. In my previous code using cookies I could set the login path so everything was redirected to that page if there was no cookie/authentication. Is this still possible under this azure ad approach?

Comment: @IrishRedneck I am using `HomePageRouteModelConvention` to change the default start page, and I also post my full steps in your another post. You can check it, hope it can help you.

Comment: I will try this out this week and let you know how it goes!